# xlsx write protection by locking cell value

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I am trying to lock the formula in Col J so it can't be manually edited,I didn't find much  on this in the docs [Enabling Cell protection in Worksheets](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_protection.html) .The file can't be closed (saved).

```
import xlsxwriter
wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('output.xlsx')
ws = wb.add_worksheet( 'output' )
ws.write_formula("J3", "=SUM(F3:H3)", 'locked') #locked not string gives NameError
wb.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you linked to seems to be exactly what you are looking for. You basically need to turn on the worksheet protection and all cells that aren't explicitly unlocked will be locked. For example:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('protection.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Turn worksheet protection on.
worksheet.protect()

worksheet.write_formula('J3', '=SUM(F3:H3)')

workbook.close()
```

Comment: so I have to `"unlcoked"` for values that I allow users to edit

Comment: Yes. That is the way Excel works. All cells are default locked, once the sheet is protected. You need to unlock cells that you want to allow the user to edit.